# storing time codes in SQL database

Tags: mysql, time

I need to store time codes of movies into a table. Example: **01:45:23:13** (1 hour, 45 minutes, 23 seconds, 13 frames.

Is it possible to store this as a real time field, or do I have to store this as a VARCHAR or so?

Comment: It's probably better to store this as an integer of seconds or frames. How will you handle different frame rates?

Comment: it depends on your need after all

Comment: @BenM: We only will use a framerate of 30 frames

Comment: So just store it as `int` of frames and convert that using your 30 FPS.

Comment: @Begueradj: We would like to make calculations with this field, so I don't want to use a VARCHAR or TEXT

Answer (score 0):

MySQL retrieves and displays `TIME` values in `'HH:MM:SS'` format (or `'HHH:MM:SS'` format for large hours values).

MySQL recognizes `TIME` values in several formats, described in Section 9.1.3, [“Date and Time Literals”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html). Some of these formats can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision.

A trailing fractional seconds part is permissible for temporal values in contexts such as literal values, and in the arguments to or return values from some temporal functions. However, when MySQL stores a value into a column of any temporal data type, it discards any fractional part and does not store it.

**So, no. You must to store in a different kind of data type.**

More info on [The TIME type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html).